# Finding unused nginx modules in the loaded module list

Tags: nginx

I want to understand nginx modules which are not used by the system even though it is loaded.
This is to identify unused nginx modules and remove from the system for security related issues.

I can able to list out all the modules loaded with below commands.
strings /usr/sbin/nginx|grep _module|grep -v configure| sort
nginx -V 2>&1 | tr ' ' '\n'

But not getting any pointers how to find unused modules and remove it.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Senthil